# OpenSimplex issues

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm following Amit's awesome tutorial:
http://www.redblobgames.com/maps/terrain-from-noise/#demo

This code:

```
from opensimplex import OpenSimplex

def simplex_noise(size):
    def noise(nx, ny):
        gen = OpenSimplex()
        # Rescale from -1.0:+1.0 to 0.0:1.0
        return gen.noise2d(nx, ny) / 2.0 + 0.5 

    value = np.zeros((size,size),dtype=np.float16)

    for y in range(size):
        for x in range(size):
            nx = x/size - 0.5
            ny = y/size - 0.5
            value[y,x] = noise(nx, ny) #(dont ask why flips x-y)


    return value.reshape(size * size).tolist();
```

Renders me this (made it in 3d):

[image]

Instead of a more randomy-noisy thing like this (in 2D, from Amit's website):

[image]

I already made this in Diamond Square algorithm but wanted to try this lib and is odd. The output is between 0 and 1.

I'm lost! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a little noise for me. Is a reshape array of value matrix !?
Why ? Try this example to have same result, maybe this help you.

```
from opensimplex import OpenSimplex
from PIL import Image

height = int(input("Enter in the map height: "))
width = int(input("Enter in the map width: "))

def main():
    simplex = OpenSimplex()
    im = Image.new('L', (width, height))
    for y in range(0, height):
        for x in range(0, width):
            value = simplex.noise2d(x , y )
            color = int((value + 1) * 128)
            im.putpixel((x, y), color)
    im.save('noise2d_output.png')
    im.show()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```